# unindexed field in appengine search document?

Tags: google-app-engine, search

In a appengine search document, can I set a field to not be indexed?

I looked at the documentation and I think this is not possible, but I don't find anywhere that concretely says so, so trying to make sure.

I wonder why this is... perhaps they are trying to prevent "abusive" use of the search by storing "too much" non-indexed information in the document... but it is pretty convenient in some cases vs having to go to another data store, especially when the total data sizes are fairly small.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the full text search service is a search index, not a data repository, so by definition everything is indexed.

You would probably struggle with this approach because the data types you put in are not necessarily what are stored, for example dates put in only have precision of a day (the time component is dropped), and numbers have truncated precision.